# If statement isn't working for simple JavaScript toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

In the `resize()` function we check if the `body` element has the class `switch`. If it contains `switch` then we remove it when `resize` is fired. If it doesn't have the `switch` class then we add it when the function is fired.

However in the snippet below when the button is clicked it doesn't work as a toggle. It gets clicked only once and it's original state cannot be restored.

Why doesn't this simple JavaScript work and what are some ways to fix this?

```js
function resize() {
  var body = document.querySelector( 'body' );
  
  if( body.classList.contains( 'switch' ) ){
    body.classList.remove( 'shrink' ); 
  }
  else {
    body.classList.add( 'shrink' ); 
  }
}

var switcher = document.getElementById( 'switch' );
switcher.addEventListener( 'click', resize );
```

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
}
.bar {
  width: 22.5rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: #555;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  position: relative;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 1.5s;
}
.knob {
  width: 12rem;
  height: 12rem;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY( -50% );
  transition-property: right, background-color;
  transition-duration: 1s, 1.5s;
}
:checked ~ label p { color: #888 }
:checked ~ label .bar { background-color: #888 }
:checked ~ label .knob {
  background-color: #777;
  right: 10.5rem
}
.shrink { transform: scale( 0.8 ) }
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    * { margin: 0 }
    html { font-size: 10px }
    html,
    body,
    main { height: 100% }
    body {
      transition-property: transform;
      transition-duration: 1s;
    }
    main {
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 6rem;
      display: flex;
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    input { display: none }
    label,
    p {
      user-select: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox" id="switch">
      <p>switch</p>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="knob"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you really have both an ID and a CSS class called `switch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking for the presence of the `switch` class, but attempting to toggle the `shrink` class. `contains('switch')` will never be false because you're not removing that class.

Answer (score 1):

> In the resize() function we check if the body element has the class switch. If it contains switch then we remove it when resize is fired.

But you're not. You're adding and removing the 'shrink' class